# Hiding the Nativescript back button but keeping the functionality

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to hide the Nativescript back button and implement it somewhere else (just below the action bar so that the drawer button can go there instead).

I disable the navigation button in the action bar like so:

```
<NavigationButton visibility="collapsed"/>
```

The problem is, when I do this the following code no longer works:

```
frameModule.topmost().goBack();
```

Any idea how I could resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You must have a bug somewhere else; `frameModule.topmost().goback();` has no issues working with or without a NavigationButton.   Disabling a NavigationButton won't disable the `goback`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not certain what could be causing the issue. As I mentioned the goback(); function works when the Navigation button is visible but when it's collapsed the goback(); function no longer works.

Comment: If you can create a sample app/page with this behavior I'll take a look at it.  I've never seen this occur.